# Сколько Ом у этого резистора?

Tags: база-данных

[Вот сам резистор](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvtvS.jpg).  Это не стёб.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это хардварная проблема.

Comment: 220 омммммммммм

Comment: Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас имеется омметр или мультиметр, то просто подключите прибор к выводам резистора и запишите показания. Мультиметр предварительно переключите в режим измерения сопротивления. Если омметр «зашкаливает» или наоборот, показывает очень маленькое значение, настройте его на подходящий диапазон. Если резистор является частью схемы, то предварительно выпаяйте его, иначе показания прибора наверняка будут неверными (меньшими).

Если Вы выпаяли его из какой-либо платы, то посмотрите в Интернете схему данной платы.

Comment: А есть еще один способ, у Вас же компонент маркированный, найдите в Интернете таблицу маркировки, например, вот: https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-43801-kak-opredelit-soprotivlenie-rezistora тут пункты 4-6